# Matrix dot product in Python returning "too many indices" error

Tags: python, index-error

```py
import numpy as np

#initialize the vectors a and b

a = np.array(input('Enter the first vector: '))
b = np.array(input('Enter the second vector: '))

#Evaluate the dot product using numpy

a_dot_b = 0
for i in range(3):
    a_dot_b += a[i] * b[i]

if a_dot_b == 0:
    print("The vectors are orthogonal")
else:
    print("Dot product = ", a_dot_b)
```

I'm trying to write a program that tells the user whether two vectors are orthogonal. When I try to run this, it says`IndexError: too many indices for array`
I don't know if it's something wrong with my loop or if it's something I'm doing wrong with inputting the vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in NumPy, you should determine the dimension of the array using [], here you give a string with zero dimension to NumPy and try to iterate, so you got the error.
you can change your code into this :

```
# get the first vector from user
firstVector = [int(i) for i in input('Enter the first vector: ').split()]
# convert into numpy array
a = np.array(firstVector)
# get the second vector from user
secondVector = [int(i) for i in input('Enter the second vector: ').split()]
# convert into numpy array
b = np.array(secondVector)
```

the rest of code is the same.

**An alternative solution for the second part of your code:**
in NumPy, you can find the dot product of two vectors only with the below codes:

```
1) sum(a * b)
2) np.dot(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `input()` returns a string, `a` and `b` are a char arrays. Thus, you need to split the input string into the vector entries and convert each element into float. Assuming you are entering the vector elements as `1,2,3`, you can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np

#initialize the vectors a and b

a = np.array([float(i) for i in input('Enter the first vector: ').split(",")])
b = np.array([float(i) for i in input('Enter the second vector: ').split(",")])

#Evaluate the dot product using numpy

a_dot_b = 0
for i in range(3):
    a_dot_b += a[i] * b[i]

if a_dot_b == 0:
    print("The vectors are orthogonal")
else:
    print("Dot product = ", a_dot_b)
```

And note that you don't need a loop to calculate the dot product. You can use `np.dot(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Could of things here. You cannot really get an array like this:

```
a = np.array(input('Enter the first vector: '))
```

`input` returns a single value. You need something along the lines

```
a = []  
n = int(input("Enter the number of elements: ")) 
  
# iterating till the range 
for i in range(n): 
    a.append(float(input(f'Enter element #{i}:'))) 
a = np.array(a)
```

and the same for `b`

Also your loop

```
for i in range(3):
...
```

assumes there are exactly three elements in both arrays. You may want to replace it with

```
for i in range(len(a)):
...
```

and also either make sure the lengths of `a` and `b` are always the same when you are asking for user input, or check for that specifically and raise an error